# Keeping UIButton highlighted

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Hey!
I have a xib file were i would like a round rect button to stay highlighted after it is pressed. I also would like to have a different button that is pressed after the first one that takes you to the next page. How can I do this. Some code would be greatly appreciated!

This is my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Test1ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2; 


}

-(IBAction) buttonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) secondButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (void)flipButton;


@end
```

This is my .m:

```
#import "Test1ViewController.h"
#import "Page2.h"

@implementation Test1ViewController

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(flipButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed {
    if ( button1.selected ) {

        Page2 *page2 = [[Page2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2" bundle:nil];
        page2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:page2 animated:YES];
        [page2 release];

    }
}




/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/


/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)flipButton {
    if ( button1.selected ) {
        button1.highlighted = NO;
        button1.selected = NO;
    } else {
        button2.highlighted = YES;
        button2.selected = YES;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: "Some code would be greatly appreciated!" Agreed.

Comment: You can specify default state image and selected state image for the button. And when user presses button just say "button.selected = YES" and it will enter selected state and keep showing the selected state image.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put the button.selected=YES. Is that the only code I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use the `highlighted` property of the button to set the state as highlighted or otherwise. However doing immediately on `Touch Up Inside` seems to reset it. So we delay the change until the next run loop starts. Do this on the method called on touch.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(flipButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}
```

and define the flip method as follows –

```
- (void)flipButton {
    if ( self.button.selected ) {
        self.button.highlighted = NO;
        self.button.selected = NO;
    } else {
        self.button.highlighted = YES;
        self.button.selected = YES;
    }
}
```

You can later check on the method called on tap of the other button whether `self.button.selected` is `YES` or not and then act on it.

```
- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed {
    if ( self.button.selected ) {
        // Load next page.
    }
}
```

**Better Approach**

Use a `UISwitch`. Don't you think that it is a natural fit.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. Unfortunately, im kind of new to all this and this makes absolutely no sense to me :D Where should I put all this code and is this all I need?

Comment: For what this question is about, yes. You will have to drag and drop two buttons and connect the `Touch Up Inside` event of one of the buttons to  `buttonPressed` and connect the other to `secondButtonPressed`. Declare both these methods and `flipButton` in the header and put this code in the `.m` files.

Comment: Hey thanks! When I do this I get 10 warnings that all say: Request for member "button" in something not a structure or a union". How do I fix this?

Comment: You will have to declare an `IBOutlet` and a property for `button` and connect it to the first button.

Comment: How do I declare flipButton in the header?

Comment: Hey thanks for all the help. Right now I am able to run the application and when I click the first button, it stays highlighted. That is great!However, the button to move to the next page does not work....any suggestions?

Comment: I have realized that even without pressing the first button, moving to the second page does not work. Hoever if I get rid of     if ( self.button.selected ) {    it works when I dont press the first button but not when I do press the first button.

Comment: How did you implement the button?

Comment: I used interface builder and did the connecting thing. In my .h i put in this:                                                                           @interface Test1ViewController : UIViewController {
 
 IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
 IBOutlet UIButton *button2; 


}

Comment: It tells me, incomplete implementation of test1ViewController and Method definition for "-buttonPressed" not found

Comment: Have you defined the method like `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;`? Because `buttonPressed` and `buttonPressed:` are two different methods

Comment: I was asking for the implementation of `secondButtonPressed`. I wanted to see why it wasn't behaving as intended.

Comment: I had it as -(IBAction)buttonPressed; and then i just changed it to -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;    That made not difference.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with this part of the code:      `- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed {
 if ( button2.selected ) {

  Page2 *page2 = [[Page2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2" bundle:nil];
  page2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  [self presentModalViewController:page2 animated:YES];
  [page2 release];
 
    }`

Comment: Ok shouldn't it be `button1.selected` since you want the page to be loaded when that button is `selected`?

Comment: I changed that and it still doesnt work. I put up the code that I have now. Thx!

Comment: In the `.m` file, `- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed {` should be `- (IBAction)secondButtonPressed:(id)sender {`

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks a bunch for all the help! This is a huge breakthrough in my development of the application! Its becasue of people like you that noobs like me can learn :D

Comment: One question, i am trying to do this for a custom round rect button and it does switch to the selected state configuration but then just back to a darker version of the default state configuration...is there a way to make it stick to the image of the selected state configuration?

Comment: Never mind, i was able to solve this problem by putting         self.button.highlighted = NO;